# How to get current index and count of itemsource from itemtemplate

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a ListView which contain some item, each item has a template of itself, my problem is how to display the current index of each item and the count of itemsource in the itemtemplate?

My ListView xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="AddTermsListView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FilterDataTemplate}"                                      
                            ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxSet}"                                                                     
                            ItemsPanel="{StaticResource WrapItemsPanelTemplate}"
                            SelectionMode="None" Padding="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"                                
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

My ItemTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FilterDataTemplate">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="White" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBox BorderBrush="#FF727272" Background="#FFD1D1D1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{How to get Index?}"/>
    <TextBox BorderBrush="#FF727272" Background="#FFD1D1D1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{How to display total of ComboBoxSet?}"/>
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Thank you :)

**EDIT**

Try binding the total items in ListView by the ComboBoxSet but still not work:

```
<TextBox BorderBrush="#FF727272" Background="#FFD1D1D1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ComboBoxSet.Count}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can show the List items count on the template by Element binding.

UPDATE: Try this code

```
<ListView x:Name="AddTermsListView">              
       <ListView.ItemTemplate   >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="300" Height="50">   
                        <TextBlock   Text="{Binding}"  Margin="0,0,20,0"/>                         
                        <TextBlock   Text="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=AddTermsListView}"  />
                    </StackPanel>                      
                </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate >          
</ListView >
```

Populate collection and set it as ItemSource of your list

```
List<string> temperatures = new List<string>();          
// Generate 10 items
for (int num = 1; num <= 10; num++)
{
  temperatures.Add("number" + num);
}   
AddTermsListView.ItemsSource = temperatures;
```

Please note that 'Items' is not your Item Source Collection Name.  [It Gets the collection used to generate the content of the ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.items%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

And if you want to show the index with each item, it s better to add an extra `Index property` to  your model class & increment it with the item when building list Item Source.

Comment: I try the Binding Element but it's not work, always show 0 value although I add some item to that listview!

Comment: Have you tried with the same code Text="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=AddTermsListView}"  ? It works for me for design time list  items. Let me check the other case.

Comment: @HanTran It works for me on both cases. Please check your code.

Comment: Also check whether all list items are populating. Am in doubt that your view is not getting the itemsource update notification.

Comment: Yes, look like it's has problem with update notification of ListView control, but why I cannot binding to the ComboBoxSet to get Count?

Comment: Please copy & use this <TextBox BorderBrush="#FF727272" Background="#FFD1D1D1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=AddTermsListView}" /> instead of yours.

Comment: Show me your c# code for building the collection. Or do one thing : just use a Stackpanel as DataTemplate with a background color & run the app. And make sure that it displays all the items in your collection.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't show the C# code, it's relate to my private project of our company, it's complex, I just create as sample as I can to reach my purpose. Furthermore, I use your code and place it outsite of the ItemTemplate and it's work...Maybe I should write a TotalCount property in the ViewModel and binding to it.